# PHP file_get_contents print php tag

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Does anyone knows an solution for the following thing:
[image]
This is my code snippet who is passed to my file-get-contents function

[image]

but when I looked in my browsers development tool i see this:
[image]

Does anyone knows why my code from the file_get_contents not is executed but the code line is printed?

Comment: Please post the *actual* code here.

Comment: `file_get_contents` retrieves the raw file and does not parse it, you are looking for `include` or `require`

Comment: I know Ant Man has just come out, but that's no excuse to post tiny screenshots...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents` just gets the raw file. You should use `include()` or `require()` instead.